# Issue in joining 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

Please have a look at the below diagram.

[image]

It says,

1. `Portfolio` has a `Provider`
2. `Portfolio` has a `Investment_Type`
3. `Client_Profile` has a `Client` and `Portfolio`

Now, I need to get the list of `Clients`, `Portfolios` allocated to each of them, finally the `Provider` Name and `Investment_Type` that each Portfolio has.

Below is my query to get the data

```
SELECT Client_Portfolio.*,
Client.Name as "Client Name",
Provider.Name as "Provider Name",
Portfolio.*
FROM Client_Portfolio
INNER JOIN Client ON Client_Portfolio.idClient = Client.idClient
INNER JOIN Portfolio ON Client_Portfolio.idPortfolio = Portfolio.idPortfolio
INNER JOIN Provider ON Portfolio.idProvider = Provider.idProvider
```

But it didn't work, it gave me the incorrect results, it only displayed 2 results belong to a one `Client` and that is all.

So, how can I achieve this task?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: hold on, hold on, I will check for the typo..But tell me whether my query is correct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: No, my query is wrong..

Comment: `Profile` or `Portfolio` (just a minor typo)? I guess you want to use `LEFT JOIN` if you don't want to miss portfolios without a provider (your schema says the provider is optional)

Comment: @Sniper sample data set and desired data will be helpful also consider adding [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) example of your schema

Comment: @knittl: Sorry, Typo. It is `Portfolio`

Comment: @knittl: Your answer is correct. Please provide it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INNER JOIN`s will only show rows where all tables provide non-null values. Since your schema contains optional providers, you will need to use some kind of outer join instead (e.g. `LEFT JOIN`):

```
SELECT Client_Portfolio.*,
Client.Name as "Client Name",
Provider.Name as "Provider Name",
Portfolio.*
FROM Client_Portfolio
INNER JOIN Client ON Client_Portfolio.idClient = Client.idClient
INNER JOIN Portfolio ON Client_Portfolio.idPortfolio = Portfolio.idPortfolio
-- show row even if it does not have a provider:
LEFT JOIN Provider ON Portfolio.idProvider = Provider.idProvider
```